# Does $f(n)$, growing slower than $n^{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$ exist, such that $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{nf(n)} < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am looking for a function $f$ satisfying the properties in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Any $f(n) \in O(\log^a n)$ with $a>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, $f(n) = (\ln n)^2$ for example.

Indeed,
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2} \leq \sum_{n=3}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}dx = \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}dx = \frac{1}{\ln 2} < \infty.
$$

Such examples are known as Bertrand series.

Comment: cool, thanks a lot!